# Error con SoftCascades en Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

estoy usando el softcascades sobre mi proyecto en Larabel 5.5, el cual usa el softdeletes, pero estoy obteniendo el error SQLSTATE 42S2 COLUMN NOT FOUND, error del cual se que sucede cuando elimino y es debido a que en mi proyecto en ese apartado no usé el convenio para nombrar atributos. Les explico
   - Tengo un modelo TipoCarro el cual tiene un nombre y tengo otro modelo llamado Carro que dentro de sus atributos tiene la llave foranea tipo_c_id, para una relacion 1:M entre TipoCarro y Carro respectivamente.
  -  El error sale al eliminar un TipoCarro que internamente eloquent busca por convenio al nombrar atribitus, el nombre del modelo_id, en este caso estaria buscando la columna tipo_carro_id,y al buscar en la tabla carros laravel no encuentra esa columna y manda el error, todo a causa de que yo no lo tengo definido de esta forma sino tipo_c_id, no lo puedo cambiar a la forma en que deberia ponerse porque ya hay trabajo hecho con esa llave foranea puesta de esa forma y seria mucho trabajo virar atras.
 - Por eso les pregunto si ***existe alguna forma de indicarle al softcascades el nombre de la columna de la llave foranea que debe buscar?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***RESUELTO*** En el metodo de la relacion, en este caso en el metodo que relaciona al modelo TipoCarro con el Carro hay que indicarle el nombre de la llave foranea en caso de no cumplir con el convenio que usa laravel.
Mas informacion de como hacerlo en el siguiente enlace
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: si agregas el código que acompaña a tu respuesta será mas didáctico para comprender tu solución

Comment: @Aprendiz  , sugerencia aceptada, agregado el enlace de la solucion arriba, gracias.